# How to authenticate NSConnection requests?

Tags: macos, distributed-objects, nsconnection

*(Let's ignore the fact that `NSConnection` is now deprecated.)*

I have a tool that accepts connections to NSConnection over a service port. I have an application that launches the tool and then connects to it. That part works.

Now, I like to make sure that only my particular app can talk to the tool and that the tool rejects connections from any other tool/app.

How do I best accomplish this?

One idea I had:

Since the app starts the tool, it could pass a "secret" to the tool as an argument, and then I pass the same secret to the tool whenever I invoke one of its functions as an NSDistributedObject. However, that would mean I have to pass that extra argument to every call I make, and I think that's unnecessary overhead.

I would think that I could accept or reject the connection right when the app opens the connection to the tool, i.e. only once. There is the `NSConnectionDelegate`, and I suspect that I'd have to implement the authentication check in its `authenticateComponents:withData:` handler, but I cannot find any examples that would explain how to do that. I mean, is there any data in that connection attempt that would identify the app that's requesting the connection, such as its PID, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you establish a connection for every call? I wouldn't think so but, if not, why do you think you'd have to pass the secret for every call? It's pretty common for the server to have a check-in method that clients have to call. You could validate the secret in that check-in method.

A malicious client might try to just skip the check-in method. You can use the `-connection:handleRequest:` method of `NSConnectionDelegate` to force them to call the check-in method. Keep a flag for every connection indicating if you've seen the check-in method. If you have, that method can just return `NO`. If you haven't, then examine the `NSDistantObjectRequest`'s `invocation`'s `selector`. If it's the check-in method, set your flag and return `NO`. If it's not, then terminate the connection.

I know the underlying ports (Mach or socket) have mechanisms for authenticating peers, but I don't see a way to get at that with the abstractions of `NSConnection` laid over them.

Finally, you are apparently wedded to `NSConnection` but this is exactly the sort of thing that the `NSXPCConnection` API is for. Among other things, it will ensure that the service is only visible to the parent app.

Comment: I know about XPC and have already implemented that part, but I need NSConnection as a fallback and test case. I'll consider your suggestion about requiring an initial "login" call. I assume that `authenticateComponents:withData:` is invoked whenever a new connection is attempted, and that would be the trigger to require the login call, right? Or did you mean something else? Not sure how `handleRequest:` is supposed to be used (can't find sample code for that, either)

Comment: I think that `authenticateComponents:withData:` is called for every message. It looks like it's intended for checksums or cryptographic signatures. The sender produces an authentication data object by processing the data components of the message it's sending. The receiver examines the data components and the authentication data object to confirm they correlate as they should. You could use a shared secret as the basis of the authentication data, if you want. That adds overhead to every call, though.

Comment: The login call would just be the first thing the parent app invokes on the root object that the tool vends. Nothing would need to trigger it. The tool would expect it for each new connection. The expectation would be established by whatever code you use to track new connections and assign them a delegate.

Comment: Ah, my bad - I meant to write `connection:shouldMakeNewConnection:`, not  `authenticateComponents` - I just copied the wrong method signature into my question. I got it working now that way: `shouldMakeNewConnection` sets a flag and requires the next call to be the login call, and all other remote callable methods will refuse to work until the login was successful.